# Changed the database I'm pointing to and now I get a "Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent."

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008, c#-4.0, authentication, session-cookies

I have an MVC 4.0 web application that worked just fine while I was using the first database (say dbo.ReportXML) but when I change the connectionString to point to the new database in Web.config (say dbo.Report4) I get the error "Server cannot modify cookies after HTTP headers have been sent." when it hits the FormsAuthentication.SignOut(); code. 
I'm baffled and my Google searches have been fruitless! Can anybody help?

Thanks in advance.
Steve

Comment: is it possible something is getting cached ? Have you tried f12 dev tools and use the "settings" tab to check "Disable cache while tool is open". Or maybe try adding a brand new connection string inside web.config.

Comment: Something has already written to the response by the time you call FormsAuthentication.SignOut().  You'll have to debug through it to figure out what is doing that.